# ASP.NET simulating users and performance testing

Tags: asp.net, performance

I have an ASP.NET application that is going to be going to production soon and I am looking for a way to simulate multiple users and find any bottlenecks in the code.  Are there any solutions out there that will accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StressStimulus](http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com/) helped us a lot. Record a macro of normal user interaction, and then bombard the app with tenfold playback.

Answer (score 0):

I use something called JMeter by the Apache Foundation - https://jmeter.apache.org/